# How did they sweep dust on the moon from inside the Apollo Lunar Lander?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, dust

I noticed from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1488/25) the phrase:

> by sweeping all the dust we could find

How did they sweep dust in the LM? And where did they sweep it to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How was dust-mitigation addressed during the Apollo program?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/how-was-dust-mitigation-addressed-during-the-apollo-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Constellation report](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/TP-2006-213726.pdf) referenced earlier, there was a sampling brush that could be used, and some spare cloth that seems to have been attempted. The dust problem was expected, especially in later missions, and they had a dust brush to brush off the dust from the lunar suits.