# How much cgi would be needed to fake apollo

Tags: apollo-program

A modern CPU is 200 gflops. A 1968 computer is 5 mflops. A few weeks to render a minute of footage.

So since there are only a few minutes of physically relevant footage (lunar rover dust trajectory, object movement, oscillations etc) it wouldn't take much it seems. Refute this

Comment: An incitement to debate the feasibility of a hoax is not a question about space exploration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we know the Apollo Moon landings are real?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28172/how-do-we-know-the-apollo-moon-landings-are-real)

Comment: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may want to have a look at this video: [Debunking Lunar Landing Conspiracies with Maxwell and VXGI](https://youtu.be/O9y_AVYMEUs)

Comment: the software wasnt there yet. solved it

Answer (score 12):

Your premise is incorrect. Apollo 11 alone generated [3 hours of footage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11_missing_tapes) on the surface. The crews had cameras running almost continuously during EVAs (although some of it was at slow speed, down to 1 fps), that requires [75 hours of footage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_program#Mission_summary). A list of footage can be found [via this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27917/lunar-rover-footage/27919#27919).

In addition, there were lots of photos, some video in Moon orbit and on the transit from/to the Moon, video during descent and ascent from the Moon. Plus all the audio and telemetry channels (NASA has 19,000 hours of recordings from Apollo 11 alone).

Comment: See also (for more information about audio recordings): https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28235/how-were-the-flight-journals-of-the-apollo-missions-originally-transcribed-recor